# java - how to compare string from construction through char[]

Tags: java, string, compare

I tried the following but could not get any answer to comparing 2 String.  How can I compare b and x and get 'true'?

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // String a = "abc";
    String b = new String("abc");
    // System.out.printf("a == b -> %b\n", (a == b));
    // System.out.printf("a.equals(b) -> %b\n", a.equals(b));
    char[] x = new char[4];
    x[0] = 'a'; x[1] = 'b'; x[2] = 'c'; x[3] = 0;
    String s = new String(x);
    System.out.printf("x = %s\n", s);
    System.out.printf("b == s -> %b\n", b == s);
    System.out.printf("b.equals(s) -> %b\n", b.equals(s));
    System.out.printf("b.compareTo(s) -> %d\n", b.compareTo(s));
  }
}

x = abc
b == s -> false
b.equals(s) -> false
b.compareTo(s) -> -1
```

Answer (score 2):

A `char` array is *not* a `String`. As it is, you're comparing the *reference values* of the objects (The `String` and the `char[]`) which will never be true.

You would either need to convert the `char` array to a `String` and use `String.equals(otherString)` or convert the `String` to a `char` array and compare the arrays with the static method from the `Arrays` class.

```
char[] x = new char[3];
x[0] = 'a'; x[1] = 'b'; x[2] = 'c';
String b = new String("abc");
String otherString = new String(x);
if (b.equals(otherString))
{
    // they match
}
```

Or using the static method from `Arrays` ...

```
char[] myStringAsArray = b.toCharArray();
if (Arrays.equals(x, myStringAsArray))
{
    // they match
}
```

As noted in Alex's answer, there's not terminating null in a Java String.

JavaDoc:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: char array x was already converted to String s, and the comparison was made between String b and String s

Comment: @user1040876 The length must be three, as I said. Just because you didn't initialize it doesn't mean it isn't there.

Comment: They won't match w/ this code; array is still four chars long.

Comment: but the problem was that I could not control the char[] size.  String s could be constructed from char[] of any size.

Comment: @user1040876 That's going to be a problem for you. You can control the length; find the 0 char. Or work in reverse, and get the string's chars.

Comment: @DaveNewton - thanks; I'd removed the extra element but hadn't changed the length of the char array in the initialization. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to terminate String with 0 in Java. And don't use `==` on strings. It will compare the reference not the content.

Comment: The == was to illustrate that did not work either.  It was not intended to return true.

Comment: Yes. Make your `char` array size 3 and remove the null termination. You've obviously just made the jump from C/C++ - it would be _very_ unusual to manipulate character arrays in C-style in Java. Also, the use of `System.out.printf` is _unusual_ for a single argument (use `+` to concatenate strings), and multiple statements on a single line is **actively discouraged**.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the trailing '0' char, use String.equals, and make the char array be three chars long.

Comment: the trailing zero did not matter.  The resulting String s constructed from x still has "abc".  But String b still cannot get compared to String s

Comment: @user1040876 The length of the array must be 3.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an array must be three.

```
 char[] x = new char[3];
 x[0] = 'a'; x[1] = 'b'; x[2] = 'c';
 String s = new String(x);
```